# Catching a value change inside an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input that suppose to contain a name, the input has change and keyup events bounded to itself, at some point in my code i'm setting the value of the input myself, but the change/keyup event doesn't catch the changed value inside the input.

here's a snippet:

```
 <input class="form-control inp-playlist-name" type="text" name="playlist" value="" placeholder="e.g. Have a Nice Day">


$('.inp-playlist-name').bind('change keyup', function(){
//do something
});

//at some point i change the value
$('.inp-playlist-name').val('A value');
```

is there any other event that can catch that kind of change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `change` event if you use Javascript to change the field's value. Instead, you can [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event yourself after making the change.

```
$('.inp-playlist-name').val('A value').trigger('change');
```

(Keep in mind that, if you're not careful, it's possible to end up with an infinite loop when doing this.)